# How can I manipulate this $X = \{ a \in Y | f(a) \}$, to go to a general term?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck with a problem in which I am trying to go from a set to a general formula.
\begin{align*} X = \{ a \in Y | f(a) \} \\
\text{if x $\in$ X, } \exists a \in Y [ f(a)]\\
\text{Assuming $x \in X$ is true, we get,}\\
a \in Y \wedge f(a)
\end{align*}

Is this valid reasoning?

Comment: Very formally, $\exists a\in Y\;(f(a)\;)$ is an abbreviation for  $ \exists a\;(a\in A \land  f(a)\;).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\begin{align} X = \{ a \in Y \mid f(a) \} \\
> \text{if }x \in X,  \exists a \in Y~[ f(a)]\end{align}$

Yes, if $x$ is in $X$, then there does exist such an element in $Y$ where $f(a)$ holds; all of the elements in $X$ do, in general, and in particular $x$ is in $Y$ and $f(x)$ is true.   It is a much stronger statement to say so.

---

The construction, $X=\{a\in Y\mid f(a)\}$, reads : "$X$ is the set of elements (say $a$) in $Y$ where the predicate $f(a)$ is true."

That is: $a\in X$, if and only if $a\in Y$ and $f(a)$.

So, iff $x\in X$, then $x\in Y$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: Did you mean iff on the last line? I am not familiar with iff-then statement. Does it mean the same as a iff b?